# strange jsf panelgroup binding -> h:selectOneMenu validation Exception

Tags: validation, jsf

lets start simple:
- an easy search form 
- two h:selectOneMenu components are declared inside a form
- the second selectOneMenu, is refreshed base on selecting an item of the first selectOneMenu (with ajax)
For this, i use a central Bean in request scope, because the two selectOneMenus are declared on many other pages, so i dont need to define the two following methods multiple times:

pageSupport:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<BranchenRubrik> getLst_branchenRubrik() {
    if(lst_branchenRubrik == null) {
        Session session = hibernate.InitSessionFactory.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            this.lst_branchenRubrik = session.createQuery("from BranchenRubrik").list();
        tx.commit();
    }
    return lst_branchenRubrik;
}

// Loading Subkats with parameter
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<BranchenRubrikSub> getBranchenRubrikSub(long p_parent) {

    List<BranchenRubrikSub> lst_branchenRubrikSub = new ArrayList<BranchenRubrikSub>();
    if(p_parent > 0) {          
        Session session = hibernate.InitSessionFactory.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            lst_branchenRubrikSub = session.createQuery("from BranchenRubrikSub BRS WHERE BRS.parentRubrik.id = :p1").setLong("p1",p_parent).list();
        tx.commit();
    }
    return lst_branchenRubrikSub;
}
```

VDL:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{searchBean2.fvz.branchenRubrikID}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bitte wählen" itemValue="0"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{pageSupport.lst_branchenRubrik}" var="rubrik" itemValue="#{rubrik.id}" itemLabel="#{rubrik.rubrik}"/>
            <f:ajax render="uiBranchenSubKat"/> 


        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputText value="Unterkategorie" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="uiBranchenSubKat" value="#{searchBean2.fvz.branchenRubrikSubID}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{pageSupport.getBranchenRubrikSub(searchBean2.fvz.branchenRubrikID)}" var="brs" itemLabel="#{brs.rubrik}" itemValue="#{brs.id}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

this works fine, i can submit the form and all data are saved and will be re-displayed.
Now, i want to include an h:panelGroup with binding to a methode, which build a pagination menue.
If i include the h:panelGroup binding="#{searchBean2.paginationMenu}"/> then, i cant submit the form, because it says that the value for the second h:selectOneMenu is not valid.

if i remove the "h:panelGroup binding" all working as expected.
The h:panelgroup can also binded to an empty methode "return new HtmlPanelGroup()"
then, the error occurs again.
looks like, that the component binding, breaks some validation.

thanks for your time

Comment: I can explain this problem if the bean is view scoped, but not if the bean is request scoped. Are you absolutely certain that your bean is request scoped? By the way, performing business logic in getters this way is a bad practice. For the proper way, check the "Populate a child menu" section at the bottom of our `selectOneMenu` wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Comment: there are no changes, with viewscope or requestscope.

it isn't a "normal" getter function, it's a standalone function. 
(no private methode, and no setter)

Something like: 
public List<Object> fncReadSubChildrenFromDb(int paratentSelectedItem) {
 // load and return 
}

it works great in many different webapplikations, but only if i create a panelGroup binding inside the page, where i use this methode, the validation error occur.
looks like, that the panelgroup binding, do some changes with the submitted values, but what :(

Comment: (cant see anything in the PhaseListener, params and values looks fine)

Note:
the load function, is defined in a central Bean, which will be used by many other forms without any errors.
I dont like to define the SelectOneMenu - lists multiple times in different Beans.
So i decided to define it in a "support bean".Your example assume that the SelectOneMenu value list is defined in the same bean.
But if you need these two SelectOneMenus multiple Time, in different forms, you have to copy the code, not so good :(

greetz

Comment: Business logic in getters is inefficient as its called on every single value expression evaluation which may occur multiple times during a single HTTP request (the result is namely not cached at all). The item values can of course go in a different bean without problems, even a differently scoped one.

Comment: Coming back to your concrete problem, an SSCCE would be helpful.